# How do I parse this file and catch all the 'Data Gather' text?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I need to parse only this one file so I don't want to learn and parse as I am running out of time.
Help me parse this in java.
Which ever has the source/code needed to get the text in the element `<seil:hasData>`.

I tried doing it using `Jena API` but I find it difficult to understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
 xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:ns1="http://testing.com/seil/v1.3/app/subk#"
 xmlns:seil="http://www.testing.com/seil/1.3/seil#"
 >
 <foaf:Agent rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/user_9876543210">
   <seil:hasAccessed>
 <seil:SeilApp rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/v1.3/app/subk_app/">
       <rdfs:label rdf:resource="SubK (Python app)"/>
    </seil:SeilApp>
  </seil:hasAccessed>
   <seil:hasActivityNode>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_114db2b2-beba-4816- a858-ee937d09b9a2">
    <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_41a897e6-2ff8-40b7-843e-f18ea4ec5100"/>
    <dc:date rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2011-12-13T13:09:26</dc:date>
  </rdf:Description>
</seil:hasActivityNode>
  </foaf:Agent>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_b54a07d3-af1b-49ef-9bf0-e28cf039f709">
  <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Recording</seil:nodeType>
  <seil:hasConnectedNode>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_eb3d6c79-f833-4cbb-a107-d5464acd4c52">
    <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
    <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_0c594e8d-9ffb-4b4b-bbca-29b6217c1308"/>
    <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-is-your-phone-number</seil:hasData>
  </rdf:Description>
   </seil:hasConnectedNode>
   <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">7c2373d7-64f3-475f-a3d7-6fff8da3d8e5</seil:hasData>
 </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_02c7f438-cc29-445b-abc1-8a1cf56ad3c0">
   <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
   <seil:hasConnectedNode>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_4c7fdae2-3d8d-46b8-a811-3da7cf545ed3">
      <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Recording</seil:nodeType>
       <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_0965d68d-f00b-47d9-8db9-ccb92c591cac"/>
       <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">3ffbab13-fc21-4323-a6db-623112f3a983</seil:hasData>
     </rdf:Description>
    </seil:hasConnectedNode>
    <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-is-your-mobile-number</seil:hasData>
  </rdf:Description>
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_03909ff1-5f0a-4519-a0e5-32825c4d12e3">
    <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Data Gather</seil:nodeType>
   <ns1:hasOptedForService rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Banking</ns1:hasOptedForService>
    <seil:hasConnectedNode>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_099d578c-c8ec-4be6-9449-b0c9257bbac3">
    <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
    <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_fbb91c3c-ae03-41f7-a9ab-2877b81bdcdc"/>
    <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">please-select-a-bank-you-prefer</seil:hasData>
     </rdf:Description>
    </seil:hasConnectedNode>
     <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1</seil:hasData>
   </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_0965d68d-f00b-47d9-8db9-ccb92c591cac">
  <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
   <seil:hasConnectedNode>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_0f9b1079-1994-4e29-a48e-88efbd588808">
    <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Recording</seil:nodeType>
    <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_1f19b932-c1b1-42e7-bcff-0ce10937e292"/>
    <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">589a1956-d530-4bc6-9e63-eaefc0b17d31</seil:hasData>
  </rdf:Description>
   </seil:hasConnectedNode>
    <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-is-your-village-name</seil:hasData>
    </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_383c65b1-9ca7-4917-8c1f-9ef85c99ef05">
     <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Recording</seil:nodeType>
      <seil:hasConnectedNode>
       <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_9884cb69-a678-4306-a7ad-564feb2659d4">
        <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
         <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_104f532a-066b-452c-9344-359e795513c7"/>
        <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-is-your-father-name</seil:hasData>
       </rdf:Description>
    </seil:hasConnectedNode>
       <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">b57a4a21-2a67-447f-9611-c4c25925c5b6</seil:hasData>
   </rdf:Description>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_0c594e8d-9ffb-4b4b-bbca-29b6217c1308">
    <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Recording</seil:nodeType>
      <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_02c7f438-cc29-445b-abc1-8a1cf56ad3c0"/>
      <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">58f62598-2467-4f05-a5b1-e796dce4693f</seil:hasData>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_5975e051-088c-46d  6-8281-43236ae15f4d">
     <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Data Gather</seil:nodeType>
    <seil:hasConnectedNode>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_fe40d751-284e-45c0-a9af-c50cc85a5d8a">
      <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
    <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_383c65b1-9ca7-4917-8c1f-9ef85c99ef05"/>
    <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-is-your-name</seil:hasData>
      </rdf:Description>
     </seil:hasConnectedNode>
         <dc:language rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">English</dc:language>
           <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1</seil:hasData>
          </rdf:Description>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_494f41b0-d4b9-4d60-adf6-40801e689068">
            <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
          <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_b54a07d3-af1b-49ef-9bf0-e28cf039f709"/>
             <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-is-your-age</seil:hasData>
            </rdf:Description>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_41a897e6-2ff8-40b7-843e-f18ea4ec5100">
          <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
            <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_5975e051-088c-46d6-8281-43236ae15f4d"/>
               <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">what-language-do-you-prefer</seil:hasData>
         </rdf:Description>
           <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_1f19b932-c1b1-42e7-bcff-0ce10937e292">
           <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
         <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_03909ff1-5f0a-4519-a0e5-32825c4d12e3"/>
            <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">kindly-select-services-you-would-prefer</seil:hasData>
          </rdf:Description>
           <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_b04f5537-e509-42e0-b0a8-b8982280494e">
            <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Data Gather</seil:nodeType>
        <ns1:hasOptedForService rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Fund transfer</ns1:hasOptedForService>
        <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">2</seil:hasData>
     </rdf:Description>
       <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_768d0f0d-d8dc-44b3-87c5-64ace8314a3e">
    <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Play Audio</seil:nodeType>
       <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_b04f5537-e509-42e0-b0a8-b8982280494e"/>
        <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">please-select-a-banking-service-you-want</seil:hasData>
  </rdf:Description>
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_fbb91c3c-ae03-41f7-a9ab-2877b81bdcdc">
      <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Data Gather</seil:nodeType>
     <ns1:hasPreferredBank rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Yes Bank</ns1:hasPreferredBank>
        <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_768d0f0d-d8dc-44b3-87c5-64ace8314a3e"/>
      <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">5</seil:hasData>
     </rdf:Description>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://testing.com/seil/node_104f532a-066b-452c-9344-359e795513c7">
        <seil:nodeType rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Recording</seil:nodeType>
         <seil:hasConnectedNode rdf:resource="http://testing.com/seil/node_494f41b0-d4b9-4d60-adf6-40801e689068"/>
        <seil:hasData rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">e513b4c8-f98d-4349-8d03-3bd332cf0f53</seil:hasData>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/)?

Comment: @user1095508 This is not a particularly clear question, you mention you've tried using the Jena API and express having difficulties with it but don't show what you tried with the Jena API.  To work with RDF you typically need to use an API like Jena or Sesame (in the Java world) to do it in a generic reusable way.  You could write something hacky with XPath/XSLT to solve your precise problem but it would only work if the RDF/XML you got was formatted exactly to your expectations.

Comment: Also the fact that you say `I am running out of time` implies that this is homework/coursework.  If this question comes into this category it is acceptable to post it but you should tag it homework and state so in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your file is stored in `src/main/resources/seil.rdf` in the current directory (you can put it where you like; I use the maven pattern where possible). First create a Jena model:

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

Then load the file into the model:

```
FileManager.get().readModel( m, "src/main/resources/seil.rdf" );
```

Now create a `Property` object for your `hasData` property:

```
String seilNS = "http://www.testing.com/seil/1.3/seil#";
Property hasData = m.getProperty( seilNS + "hasData" );
```

And finally iterate over the statements that have any subject, any object and `hasData` as predicate:

```
for (Iterator<Statement> i = m.listStatements( null, hasData, (RDFNode) null ); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Statement s = i.next();
    System.out.println( String.format( "%s has-data %s", s.getSubject().getURI(), s.getLiteral().getLexicalForm() ));
}
```

Output:

```
http://testing.com/seil/node_41a897e6-2ff8-40b7-843e-f18ea4ec5100 has-data what-language-do-you-prefer
http://testing.com/seil/node_fe40d751-284e-45c0-a9af-c50cc85a5d8a has-data what-is-your-name
http://testing.com/seil/node_0f9b1079-1994-4e29-a48e-88efbd588808 has-data 589a1956-d530-4bc6-9e63-eaefc0b17d31
http://testing.com/seil/node_4c7fdae2-3d8d-46b8-a811-3da7cf545ed3 has-data 3ffbab13-fc21-4323-a6db-623112f3a983
http://testing.com/seil/node_768d0f0d-d8dc-44b3-87c5-64ace8314a3e has-data please-select-a-banking-service-you-want
http://testing.com/seil/node_383c65b1-9ca7-4917-8c1f-9ef85c99ef05 has-data b57a4a21-2a67-447f-9611-c4c25925c5b6
http://testing.com/seil/node_03909ff1-5f0a-4519-a0e5-32825c4d12e3 has-data 1
http://testing.com/seil/node_0c594e8d-9ffb-4b4b-bbca-29b6217c1308 has-data 58f62598-2467-4f05-a5b1-e796dce4693f
http://testing.com/seil/node_099d578c-c8ec-4be6-9449-b0c9257bbac3 has-data please-select-a-bank-you-prefer
...
```

There are many others ways of doing this. Suggest you read the [Jena documentation](http://incubator.apache.org/jena), and then ask follow-up questions as you need to. I also agree with RobV: if this is work for your education course, you should say so up front. Professors can read StackOverflow as well!